# Lógica com callback

Tags: javascript, html5, callback

Galera estou com um pequeno problema e gostaria de um auxilio para entender e se possível uma indicação dos Srs para ajudar este problema.

Vamos ao inicio, atualmente possuo um loop, estou fazendo ele em um for ficando algo parecido do codigo abaixo:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1500; i++){
 console.log("Valor "+i);
}
```

Dentro deste loop estou chamando uma função que está atualizando alguns informações, e nesta mesma função estou usando callback no final. (pelo meu entendimento o callback seria para dar tipo de um pause no codigo sendo que so vai continuar se houver o callback certo? ) O codigo esta abaixo

```
var Anonimo = {

  minhaFuncao: function(indice,callback){
    //faz algumas coisas

    //finaliza com callback
    callback(retornaAlgumaVariavel);
  }

}
```

Até aqui beleza.. Meu codigo completo ate aqui ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
var Anonimo = {

  minhaFuncao: function(indice,callback){
    //faz algumas coisas

    //finaliza com callback
    callback(retornaAlgumaVariavel);
  }

}


for(var i = 0; i < 1500; i++){
 console.log("Valor "+i);

 Anonimo.minhaFuncao(i, function(variavelRetorno){
  console.log("Entrou no indice "+i);
 });
}
```

pelo meus debug está tendo a saída corretamente que seria, a cada indice do loop está executando o callback.. Exemplo

```
Valor 1
Entrou no indice 1
Valor 2
Entrou no indice 2
[....]
```

O problema está sendo no seguinte item... quando eu chamo a "minhaFuncao" eu passo o callback que é para executar algo quando finlizar a execução dele, neste caso estou passando mais uma função que possui também um callback... algo da seguinte maneira:

```
var OutroAnonimo = {

  outraFuncao: function(callback){
    //faz algumas coisas

    //finaliza com callback
    callback();
  }

}
```

O meu codigo completo ficou da seguinte maneira

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1500; i++){
 console.log("Valor "+i);

 Anonimo.minhaFuncao(i, function(variavelRetorno){
  console.log("Entrou no indice "+1);

  OutroAnonimo.outraFuncao(function(){
    console.log("Passou aqui...");
  });
 });
}
```

O erro está no seguinte item, no Loop, eu passo pelo primeiro e segundo console.log porém quando chamo a "outraFuncao" ela é ignorada, melhor explicando, o o laço repetir 1500 vezes, no debug sai a mensagem "Valor e Entrou no indic..." porém depois que passou as 1500 vezes aparece as mensagens "Passou aqui".

A minha duvida final é, o que eu fiz de errado? ou o que faço para melhorar isso? Preciso que execute da seguinte maneira...

O loop inicia no 0, chama a função "minhaFuncao" depois que ela é finalizada chama a "outraFuncao" depois que ela finalizou eu vou para a posição 1, 2, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é o mesmo problema [desta pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127425/129). Ou seja, quando essa callback for chamada (uma vêz que é assíncrona) o loop já acabou e o `i` mudou de valor entretanto. Por isso quando usas o `i` dentro da callback a variável já não é o que pensas. Há outro [caso relacionado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1238/129).

No teu caso podes resolver de maneira simples uma vez que estás a passar o `i` para o método `Anonimo.minhaFuncao`. Ora se usares esse `i` que foi "consumido" pela função então podes passá-lo de volta na callback assim:

```
var Anonimo = {

  minhaFuncao: function(indice, callback){
    //faz algumas coisas

    //finaliza com callback
    callback(indice, retornaAlgumaVariavel);
  }

}
```

e no loop usar:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1500; i++){
 console.log("Valor " + i);

 Anonimo.minhaFuncao(i, function(indice, variavelRetorno){
   console.log("Entrou no indice " + indice);
```

Se quiseres forçar que tudo aconteça de maneira sequencial podes fazer assim:

```
function processar(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) return;
    var nr = arr.shift(); // e aqui encurta ao mesmo tempo a array
    console.log("Valor " + nr);
    Anonimo.minhaFuncao(nr, function(ind, variavelRetorno) {
        console.log("Entrou no indice " + ind);
        OutroAnonimo.outraFuncao(function() {
            console.log("Passou aqui... e terminou o indice", ind);
            processar(arr);
        });
    });
}

// para gerar o conteudo
var valores = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    valores.push(i);
}
processar(valores);
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afgbmm7u/