# var, const ou let? Qual usar?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, ecmascript-6

Recentemente descobri a existência do `let` e `const` mas agora estou na dúvida qual usar constantemente?

E por que nunca vejo códigos com `let` ou `const`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Versão curta:

Quando devo usar:

- `var`: nunca mais
- `const`: sempre que possível
- `let`: quando a variável precisar de ser sobreescrita

#### Versão longa:

A versão 6 da ECMAScript trouxe consigo novos comandos para declarar variáveis, o `let` e o `const`. Isto veio, finalmente corrigir problemas que o `var` tinha, e na prática não devemos usar mais `var`. Continua a ser importante declarar variáveis mas agora temos duas opções:

- `const`

O `const` deve ser usado em casos onde a variável não precise ser reatribuída, sobrescrita. Esta é a maioria dos casos. O `const` bloqueia a variável a um valor constante e vai dar erro se for reatribuída, ela fica como que em "modo só de leitura`, então:

```
const a = 10;
a = 20; // vai dar erro
```

mas vale a pena observar que `const obj = {}` permite modificar o objeto, com por exemplo `obj.foo = 'bar'` mas não permite re-declarar `const obj = {novo: 'objeto'}`.

- `let`

O `let` é a nova maneira de declarar variáveis que precisam ser sobrescritas. O caso mais comum é uma iteração de um loop, onde a variável a iterar é sobrescrita *N* vezes durante o loop.

Caracteristicas em comum de `let` e `const`:

- Ambos `let` e `const` não permitem que uma variável seja re-declarada. Tal era permitido com `var`, sem que avisos fossem dados, criando bugs difíceis de detectar.
- Ambas declaram a variável no escopo e `bloco` em que estão, não permitindo dentro da mesma função ou bloco re-declarar a mesma variável.

Estas novas versões ainda não são usadas diretamente nos browsers porque o suporte ainda não é universal, mas usam-se já em ambientes [pré-transpilados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/129). O `var` é portanto desaconselhado em código novo.

Comment: Isso vale para Javascript e typescript?

Comment: @Luhhh sim, é questão de boas práticas para evitar erros. O typescript ajuda a minimizar o problema, mas a resposta é válida na mesma