# Contador de dias transcorridos desde uma determinada data, usando o <form>

Tags: javascript

Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse com esse script.

Como na imagem, eu preciso pegar a data que irei inserir nos espaços em branco e contar quantos dias se passaram até o dia tal.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você simplesmente quer que alguém faça por você? Ou está com dificuldade em algo?

Comment: Eu estou realmente precisando de ajuda, no meu curso, ainda não chegamos a ver const, ainda usamos var. Passei a tarde lendo em foruns e outros sites, mas estão muito evoluidos pro que ainda estamos vendo no cur, mas de qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: De nada. Indicação de leitura: [**var, const ou let? Qual usar?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206117/18246)

Comment: diga, o formato tem que ser mes/dia/ano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você subentendeu o propósito do site.

De qualquer forma, seu problema é bem simples e pode ser resolvido com poucas linhas de código.

Não fiz tudo por você porque, como já dito, este não é o propósito do site, mas aqui vai uma ideia base de como pode ser feito.

Subtrair uma data de outra data retorna um valor numérico, este valor corresponde à quantidade de milissegundos transcorridos dentre a primeira data e segunda. Então, tendo esta quantidade em mãos, só é necessário usar um pouco a boa e velha matemática básica para obter a quantidade de dias transcorridos entre estas duas datas.

```js
const txtData = document.getElementById('data');
const txtDias = document.getElementById('dias');
const btComparar = document.getElementById('comparar');
btComparar.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);

function buttonClick(){
  var dtTarget = new Date(txtData.value);

  var diff = diferencaEmDias(new Date(), dtTarget);
  console.log(diff);
  
  txtDias.value = diff;
}

function diferencaEmDias(dataPrincipal, dataSecundaria) {
  return Math.round((dataPrincipal - dataSecundaria)/(1000*60*60*24)) - 1;
}
```

```html
Data: <input type="date" id="data" />
Dias: <input type="text" id="dias" />

<button id="comparar"> Comparar </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que o formato de entrada da data é MM/DD/AAAA, e a data final seria a data atual. Portanto a data atual deve ser formatada para MM/DD/AAAA para que se possa fazer os devidos cálculos.

Quando são necessários cálculos entre datas, lembre-se da língua franca do javascript: milissegundos.

Para podermos fazer cálculos entre datas, usamos `getTime()` que retorna o número de milissegundos entre a meia-noite do dia 1º de janeiro de 1970 e a data fornecida.

Daí é só fazer a diferença.

```js
function calc() {
 //pega o valor (data) digitada no campo (input) de id=dataInicial
    var inicial = document.getElementById("dataInicial").value;
 var DataDesde = new Date(inicial);
 
 var date = new Date();
 //data atual formatada para MM/DD/AAAA
    DataHoje = new Date(((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear()));
 
 var difTempo = Math.abs(DataHoje.getTime() - DataDesde.getTime());
 var difDias = Math.ceil(difTempo / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
 
 document.getElementById('dias').value = difDias;
 
 document.getElementById("resultado").className="show";
 
}

function esc() {
 document.getElementById("resultado").className="hide";
}
```

```css
 .hide{
  display:none;
 }
 .show{
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
Entre com o formato da data MM/DD/AAAA<br>
Data: <input type="text" id="dataInicial"><br>
<div id="resultado" class="hide">
Transcorridos <input type="text" id="dias" size="3"> dias.<br>
</div>
<input type="reset" value="Limpar" onclick="esc()"> <input type="submit" onclick="calc()" value="Calcular">
</form>
```