# Copiando uma imagem de uma div para outra - Métodos em Jscript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou com uma imagem e uma div `conteudo-img`. 
Ao clicar na imagem ela tem  que ser copiada para a div `conteudo-img`, quais métodos posso usar para fazer esta cópia e qual a mais viável via  **javaScript**.

```css
#images{
float:left;
}

#conteudo-img{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #f1f;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="images"> 
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
 </div>
 <div id="conteudo-img"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
 #images{
  float:left;
 }

 #conteudo-img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f;
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="random_id"> 
  <div class="img">
   <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
   <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
   <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
   <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="conteudo-img"> </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar `target.appendChild(image.cloneNode());` onde [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) é o método que procuras para duplicar elementos do DOM. Se usares `.cloneNode(true)` em elementos que tenham descendência (que não é o caso do teu HTML) podes incluir nessa cópia a descendência também.

```js
const images = document.getElementById('images');
const target = document.getElementById('conteudo-img');
images.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const image = e.target;
  target.appendChild(image.cloneNode());
});
```

```css
#images {
  float: left;
}

#conteudo-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="images">
    <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
    <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
    <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
    <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  </div>
  <div id="conteudo-img"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O que seria este `const`? É como definir uma variável?

Comment: @Sora exato, podes ler mais sobre isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206121/129

Comment: Ao invés de passar a id da div como parâmetro, posso passar a class também por exemplo??

Comment: @Sora depende. Se houver só um elemento podes usar `.querySelector('nomeDaClasse')`. Se tiveres vários elementos com essa classe tens de iterar. Mostra o caso de HTML que tens que posso dar um exemplo.

Comment: Alterei a minha pergunta e fiz um novo código onde requer o nome da classe como parâmetro

Comment: @Sora a minha resposta é válida na mesma se quiseres copiar só a `img`. Ou queres copiar a `div` à volta da img?

Comment: Somente a img, pensei que não era válida por causa desta linha:
`const images = document.getElementById('images');`
Porém testei e deu certo, vou marcar sua resposta como válida em breve
Obrigado @Sergio !!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim com `JS`

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll('img')

for(let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
  img[i].onclick = function(){
    let attrImage = this.getAttribute('src')
    
    document.getElementById('conteudo-img').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ attrImage +'">'
  }
}
```

```css
#images{
float:left;
}

#conteudo-img{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #f1f;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="images"> 
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
 </div>
 <div id="conteudo-img"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ou tambem pode usar `jquery`

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
  var image = $(this).attr('src')
  
  $('#conteudo-img').append('<img src="'+ image +'">')
})
```

```css
#images{
float:left;
}

#conteudo-img{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #f1f;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="images"> 
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/d61c/f/2015/256/c/7/dipper_ice_cream_splat_icon___free_to_use_by_icelemontea83-d99f4z7.gif"><br>
 </div>
 <div id="conteudo-img"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vou estudar esta codificação, vlw !!!

Comment: A resposta é válida mas se vais usar HTML acho mais seguro fazer append de `this.outerHTML`. Fica menos dependente de variacões no HTML como classes ou campos `data-` que esses elementos possam ter.

Comment: @Sergio Com toda certeza rsrs seu exemplo é muito mais valido do que o meu. Eu quis apenas mostrar uma forma de como fazer.

Comment: Não concordo com _"muito mais valido do que o meu"_. A tua resposta é boa/válida. Foi só um comentário/sugestão.

Comment: @Sergio estou sempre aprendendo com suas dicas aqui, sempre acompanho suas respostas. Valeu ;)