# javascript, uso do prompt para colher dados

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        /* calcular a media de 4 notas */


        var n1 = 10
        var n2 = 10
        var n3 = 10
        var n4 = 10

        var media = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4

        document.write("Sua média:", media);

</script>
```

Seguinte, eu queria usar o *Prompt mdn* pra digitar as variáveis, invés de deixar elas predefinidas.

Queria também criar uma função pra digitar uns textos predefinidos, invés de ficar usando `document.write()` toda hora.

Sou iniciante, se puderem me ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que o `promprt`, à semelhança do `alert`, bloqueia a execução do código podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const nrDeNotas = 4; // talvez no futuro isto também seja um prompt('Quantas notas?');

const notas = Array(nrDeNotas)
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => prompt('Insira a nota nr ' + (i + 1)))
  .map(Number);

const media = notas.reduce((soma, nota) => soma + nota, 0) / nrDeNotas;
document.write('A média é de ' + media + ' valores');
```

Podes fazer isso com menos código mas talvez fique mais difícil de lêr:

```js
const media = ['', '', '', ''].reduce((soma, nota, i, arr) => soma + Number(prompt('Insira uma nota')) / arr.length, 0);
document.write('A média é ' + media);
```

Comment: Meu, muito bom! eu jamais imaginaria fazer algo assim, muito foda! to impressionado meu... Eu não sabia o que era const, mas to fazendo a licao de casa aqui.

Comment: eu to achando incrivel que vc responde de uma forma que eu jamais imaginaria.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou estudar sobre const!

Comment: @MSHijo fico contente de ter ajudado. Se a resposta solucionou o teu problema podes marcar como aceite. E se quiseres podes usar `var` mas lê aqui sobre isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206121/129

Comment: Nunca usar! haha eu ri kk...

Comment: e eu usei um monte no codigo... Muito obrigado pela ajuda sergio!