# Por que é possível alterar um valor de array ou objeto de dentro de uma constante?

Tags: javascript, objetos, constantes

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

array[1] = 2;

console.log(array); //- ['a',2,'c','d']
```

Nesse exemplo que dei, alterei o valor da constante dinamicamente, também, é possível fazer o mesmo com objetos. Gostaria de saber o motivo de isso ser possível, pois teoricamente o valor da constante não poderia ser alterada

Comment: Se é constante é constante digo eu com os nervos. Qual seria a necessidade de alterar um valor que vamos declarar como `const`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 16):

Porque quem é constante é o valor colocado ali no identificador e, ao contrário do que as pessoas pensam, o conteúdo desse identificador (que parece variável, mas não podemos chamá-lo assim porque ele não varia) é uma referência para o objeto. Este valor é constante, portanto não pode apontar para outro *array* neste identificador. Mas o objeto em si não é constante então pode mexer nele como quiser. É como se tivesse um envelope com dados dentro e fora dele, neste caso não pode mexer nos dados de fora, mas pode mexer no que está dentro.

Tem linguagens que conseguem proibir mexer no que está dentro. Em JS é bem limitado, e no *array* não tem como.

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
array[1] = 2;
console.log(array);
array = [1, 2]; //dá erro
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/ConstChange.js).

Answer (score 15):

Como diria um antigo professor meu:

> *Não confunda "arquipelago de Fernando de Noronha" com "magrelo fumando maconha"*. Podem soar parecidos, mas são completamente distintos.

Ele dizia isso basicamente no sentido de nem tudo é o que parece.

O termo `const` no JavaScript define uma **referência** constante a um objeto. Isto é, a referência não poderá ser sobrescrita. Uma vez que a referência aponte para um objeto, não poderá **receber** outro objeto.

```js
const number = 2;

number = 3;
```

Perceba que tentando sobrescrever o objeto em `number` dá erro. Porém, ser constante é diferente de ser imutável. Um objeto imútavel não pode sofrer mutações e, "se sofrer", define outro objeto. Por exemplo, se eu tenho o número inteiro, que é imutável, 1, e incremento-o em uma unidade eu passo a ter o objeto 2, que é independente do original 1. Por isso, mesmo assumindo ele como constante, não posso modificá-lo:

```js
const number = 1;

number++;
```

O mesmo erro será apresentado, pois o objeto será constante e imutável, diferente de um *array* que é um tipo mutável. Mesmo atribuindo-lhe uma referência constante, o objeto continua sendo mutável, permitindo sofrer mutações sem representar outro objeto:

```js
const arr = [];

arr.push(1);

console.log(arr);
```

A [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) comenta sobre:

> A declaração `const` cria uma referência somente leitura a um valor. Isso não significa que esse valor é imutável, apenas que o identificador da variável constante não pode ser alterado. Se o conteúdo do identificador for um objeto, os parâmetros desse objeto poderão ser alterados, por exemplo.

Outras leituras interessantes:

- [var, const ou let? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206117/5878)
- [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/5878)

Se preferir *algo* mais oficial:

- [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

Answer (score 7):

Você pode alterar as propriedades de um objeto declarado como `const`, o que você não pode é redeclará-lo.

Você pode tanto alterar os valores da array declarada como `const` (ou objetos `{}`) como pode adicionar novos itens:

```js
const array = ["a","b","c","d"]
array[1] = 2
array.push("3")
console.log(array) //- ['a',2,'c','d','3']
```

O `const` não define um valor inalterável de uma variável, ele define uma referência inalterável para a variável. Ou seja, uma vez que você declarou a variável como `const`, essa variável não poderá mais ser redeclarada, mas podem ser alteradas as suas propriedades, se ela as tiver, como é o caso de arrays, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Em JavaScript, as variaveis complexas ou objetos(**objects**, **arrays**, **functions**, **date**) são mutáveis. Isto significa que suas reatribuições ou atualizações acontecem por referência, ou seja, mantem-se o mesmo local de memória e altera-se somente o valor.

Já os primitivos (`number`, `string`, `boolean`) são imutáveis, ou seja, não permitem reatribuição por referência.

Os declaradores `const` `let` e `var` alteram a habilidade de reatribuição por valor, ou seja, quando um novo valor é criado em um outro local de memória e o nome da variável aponta para este novo valor.(O `const` inibe esta habilidade.)

Em objetos, isto significaria basicamente mudá-lo por completo, toda a sua estrutura.

Um `const` no objeto só impediria essa reatribuição completa de sua estrutura por um novo objeto em um novo endereço de memória.

Mas como o objeto é mutavel, você pode continuar mudando a sua estrutura interna por referencia ao endereço daquele objeto.

Tente fazer `array=[1,2,3,4]` nas linhas mais a baixo e verá que não irá funcionar.

Mas, se você usar o `let`, ao invés de `const`, esta alteração completa do objeto `array` será possível.