# Como deixar um array vazio (apagar todos os elementos) em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array de objetos e quero deixar ele vazio, removendo todos os seus elementos. Como faço ?

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Comment: É muito mais fácil e rápido você atribuir `[]` à variável que continha a lista de objetos. Se fizer questão de apagar um por um, poderia fazer um loop: while (matriz.length > 0) matriz.shift();

Comment: Você pode apenas atribuir um array vazio, como o exp falou, ou utilizar o método `shift` dessa forma: `array.shift(0, array.length)`.

Comment: como comentou o @epx, `nome-da-variavel = []` ou `nome-da-variavel.length = 0`

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, o método `Array.prototype.shift` não possui tais argumentos.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal pela ajuda

Comment: @LuizFelipe Oops, era `splice`. Eu confundi na hora, desculpa. Correção: `array.splice(0, array.length)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não importando os valores de um array, são métodos válidos para esvaziar um array `arr`:

#### Alternativa 1: Redefinir a variável (ou propriedade) com um array vazio

```
arr = [];
```

Esse código vai redefinir a variável `arr` para um novo array vazio. Note que a mesma coisa também pode ser feita se ele estiver definido em uma propriedade de um objeto.

É ideal se você não tem outras referências para o array original `arr`, uma vez que isso *não* modifica o array original, apenas o substitui por um outro novo e vazio.

É importante tomar cuidado com esta alternativa tendo em vista que, se você tiver referências ao array `arr` em outras partes do seu código, elas ficarão inalteradas. Em suma, utilize esta alternativa somente quando você não está mantendo outras referências ao array original — que não está sendo, de fato, esvaziado, apenas substituído em **um** (e não todos) determinado local.

Esta é a alternativa mais rápida.

E este código mostra o problema da referência se o devido cuidado não for tomado:

```js
let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
let arr2 = arr1;  // Referência à `arr1` em outra variável. 

// Note que estamos apenas substituindo o valor da variável `arr1`.
// Não estamos, de fato, apagando nenhum dos elementos do array.
arr1 = [];

console.log(arr2); //=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Vale observar também que, se o array tiver sido declarado com `const`, não é possível utilizar esta alternativa. No entanto, modificações ao array em si ainda são válidas, conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432211/69296) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/333080/69296).

*Todas as soluções a seguir modificarão o array original (e, portanto, refletirão alterações em todas as referências).*

#### Alternativa 2: Zerar a propriedade `length`

```
arr.length = 0;
```

Isso irá limpar o array existente ao setar sua propriedade `length` para zero. Basicamente, a propriedade `length` dos arrays é um *setter* que, quando alterado, é capaz de modificar o array para se adequar ao novo valor.

#### Alternativa 3: `Array.prototype.splice`

```
arr.splice(0, arr.length);
```

Utilizar o método `Array.prototype.splice` funcionará perfeitamente para remover todos os itens de `arr`. No entanto, como esse método retorna um array com todos os itens *removidos*, acabará retornando uma cópia do array original (já que todos foram removidos). Apesar disso, *benchmarks* demonstram que isso não implica em nenhum custo adicional em performance.

#### Alternativa 4: Utilizar `Array.prototype.pop` até esvaziar o array

```
while (arr.length) {
  arr.pop();
}
```

Essa solução utiliza o `Array.prototype.pop` para remover o último elemento do array. Utiliza-se o laço `while` para repetir a remoção dos elementos finais até que o array tenha sido completamente esvaziado.

Essa solução não é muito sucinta e também é a menos performática de todas as apresentadas.

## Considerações sobre *performance*

De todos as alternativas apresentadas acima, 1 é a mais rápida, visto que não apaga o array de forma propriamente dita. Apenas modifica a variável que o continha com um novo e vazio array.

No entanto, quando apagar os elementos do array original é realmente necessário, as alternativas 2 e 3 são muito similares em performance e são significativamente superiores em relação à alternativa 4. Para resultados, referir a [este *benchmark*](https://jsben.ch/hyj65).

---

> Esta é uma adaptação deste excelente [esforço coletivo (resposta)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/7445826) do Stack Overflow em Inglês.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Luiz.