# Retornar valor da função executada por KeyUp no campo origem em VUE

Tags: vue.js

Como faço para que o valor de retorno dessa função, seja inserido no campo em que está executando o KeyUp?

```
<input type="text" v-model="valor_calc_dinheiro" v-on:keyup.stop.prevent="mascara_dinheiro($event.target.value)"           ref="valor_calc_dinheiro">

mascara_dinheiro : function(valor){
v=valor.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1.$2")
alert(v);
},
```

Comment: `this.valor_calc_dinheiro = valor.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1.$2")`

Answer (score 0):

Passa só o evento e assim tens disponível o `event.target` por exemplo...

Ou seja:

```
<input type="text" v-model="valor_calc_dinheiro" v-on:keyup.stop.prevent="mascara_dinheiro($event)"           ref="valor_calc_dinheiro">
```

E depois no método:

```
mascara_dinheiro: function(e){
    const v = e.target.value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1.$2")
    alert(v);
    e.target.value = v;
},
```

Nota: repara que coloquei `const v` e não somente `v`. Deves evitar variáveis globais, é sempre importante declarar variáveis antes de as usar. Podes ler mais sobre isso aqui: [var, const ou let? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206117/129)