# Axios GET Request Response is Undefined

Tags: javascript, express.js, http-request, axios, ejs

I'm trying to make an **axios call** in my Node JS Express app and sending the data to my index.ejs file. 
The problem is that i can see the data in my callApijavascript file but i **cant access the response** in my app.js (**undefined value**).

This is the relevant code from my **app.js** file:

```
 //iNDEX pAGE RENDER
app.get('/', function (req, rep) {
    var response = callApi.GetAll();
    var users = response.users;
    var activities = response.activities;
    console.log('Users ' + users);
    console.log('Activities ' + activities);
    rep.render('index', {
        users: users,
        activities: activities
    });
});
```

Here's my **callApi.js**
*the logs here return the api data perfectly*

```
var GetAll = function () {
  axios.all([
      axios.get(initGet.uri + 'users/'),
      axios.get(initGet.uri + 'activities/')
    ])
    .then(axios.spread(function (userResponse, activitiesResponse) {
      console.log('User', userResponse.data);
      console.log('Activities', activitiesResponse.data);
      return {
        users: userResponse.data,
        activities: activitiesResponse.data
      };

    }));

};
module.exports = {
  GetAll: GetAll
};
```

My **Error** when i run index.ejs
{"error":{"message":"Cannot read property 'users' of undefined"}}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: favor traduzir sua pergunta, este é o Stackoverflow em português

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se `GetAll` é uma função ela precisa de ter um `return`. Neste momento assim como está a função não retorna nada... quando deveria retornar uma Promise.

Adiciona um `return` aqui:

```
var GetAll = function () {
  return axios.all([
```

Repara ainda que para consumires o resultado de uma Promise tens de usar o `then`. Assim o resto do código tem de estar dentro de um `then`. Ou seja:

```
callApi.GetAll().then(response => {
    var users = response.users;
    // o resto do código aqui...
});
```

Duas sugestões:

- usa letras grandes só para construtores. Quando vejo `GetAll` penso que a intenção é usar `new GetAll();`, que não é o caso.
- usa [`const` e `let`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206121/129) sempre que possível. Deixa a "velhinha" `var` ficar para a história.

Comment: Muito obrigado agora funciona!
Consegui tudo o queria!

Comment: @AfonsoMartinho ótimo! Se quiseres podes clicar para marcar a resposta como aceite.