# Não consigo achar o botão com o querySelector

Tags: javascript, classes, seletores

Olá,estou tentando achar um botão pelo document.querySelector porém não estou conseguindo..Tentei procurar ele com o comando:

```
document.querySelector("button.tabindex[class='btn btn-inverse btn-large pull-right']");
```

O comando está errado??

No elemento do botão diz assim:

```
<button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large"> Botao1 </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso aqui `button.tabindex` está procurando por um elemento `<button class='tabindex'>`. Outro ponto é que o elemento que você está buscando não possui classe `pull-right`, logo o seletor não irá bater.

Pode fazer a consulta assim:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-large[tabindex="-1"]')

console.log(`outer: ${button.outerHTML}`)
```

```html
<button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large"> Botao1 </button>
```

Comment: Posso usar isto: const button = document.querySelector('button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-large[tabindex="-1"]') e depois button.click();  ??

Comment: @lololololo nesse caso, `querySelector` irá retornar um `HTMLButtonElement`, então sim.

Comment: posso trocar o const pelo var?

Comment: [`var`, `const` ou `let`? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206117/4808)

Comment: Ok,muito obrigado <3

Answer (score 0):

Sim, está incorreto para acessar um propriedade que não é o id nem a classe usasse `[propriedade="valor"]`, igual ao que fez para as classes. Ao usar o seletor `.tabindex` você está procurando um elemento com a classe `tabindex`

Correto:

```
button[tabindex][class='btn btn-inverse btn-large pull-right']
```

Ou ainda:

```
button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-large.pull-right[tabindex]
```

Comment: ficaria assim então var botao = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-large[tabindex]'); ??

Comment: Sim, ou usando o outro seletor para classe

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia colocar um id nesse botão, além de ser mais fácil, ficaria um código bem mais limpo e visível

ex : `<button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large" id= "idBOTAO" > Botao1 
 </button>`

na chamada do query você simplesmente faria

```
const button = document.querySelector('#idBOTAO')

console.log(button)
```

espero que tenha ajudado ;)

Comment: com o id seria mais complicado, pois eu teria que colocar o ID toda hora, porque eu fico atualizando a pagina constantemente