# Por que objetos literais são declarados com const no JavaScript atualmente?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaração-de-variável, ecmascript-5

Por causa do EcmaScript 6 vejo exemplos que declaram objetos literais com a palavra reservada `const`.

Exemplo do código:

```
// Versão utilizada atualmente
const obj = {
   x: 'example'
};

// Versão utilizada anteriormente no EcmaScript 5
var obj = {
   x: 'example'
};
```

Basicamente, as minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Isso é feito para manter o objeto imutável?
- É uma proteção para evitar que a variável seja sobrescrita indevidamente pelo programador?
- É uma prevenção da criação de variáveis e funções com o mesmo nome por esquecimento?

PS: A dúvida não é sobre objetos literais, mas sim sobre essa prática de utilizar `const` para declará-los.

Comment: Só pra constar que `const` **não** torna o objeto imutável. Para isso, você deve utilizar o `Object.freeze`.

Comment: Complementando o comentário anterior... `const` torna a variável imutável, porém o que a variável possui não é o objeto em si, mas a sua referência

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206121/112052

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em EcmaScript 6 não deve usar-se mais o `var`. Daí que o `const` ou o `let` são as opções modernas, e essa é a única razão de não se usar mais o `var`.

A recomendação não está escrita na especificação de ES6 mas é a razão pela qual `let` e `const` foram criadas. `var` é uma maneira de declarar variáveis com lacunas graves e por isso recebeu substitutos fortes (`let` e `const`) que cobrem as áreas onde `var` poderia ser usando, deixando-o obsoleto.

Há uma outra resposta completa sobre isso aqui: [var, const ou let? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206117/var-const-ou-let-qual-usar)

Em relação às tuas dúvidas:

> Isso é feito para manter o objeto imutável?

Não, é para fazer a referência ao objeto imutável. Para fazer o objeto em si (e a referência) imutáveis deves usar o [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

```
const obj = Object.freeze({
   x: 'example'
});
```

> É apenas uma proteção para evitar que a variável seja sobrescrita?

Sim. Mas se a intenção for poder re-escrever a variável, então devemos usar o `let`

> É uma prevenção da criação de variáveis e funções com o mesmo nome?

Sim.

Answer (score 5):

**A Palavra Reservada `CONST`**

> A palavra `const` é um **pouco enganosa**. **NÃO** define um **valor constante** e sim uma **referência constante** para um **valor**.
>
> Por causa disso, **não podemos alterar valores primitivos constantes**, **mas podemos alterar as propriedades de objetos constantes**.

**Valores Primitivos**

> Se atribuirmos um **valor primitivo a uma constante**, **não podemos alterar o valor primitivo**

```
const PI = 3.141592653589793;
PI = 3.14;      // Isso dará um erro
PI = PI + 10;   // Isso também dará um erro
```

**Objetos Constantes**

> Você **pode alterar as propriedades de um objeto constante**, pois eles **podem mudar**. Mas você **NÃO pode reatribuir um objeto constante**.

```
// Você pode criar um objeto const:
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

// Você pode alterar uma propriedade:
car.color = "red";

// Você pode adicionar uma propriedade:
car.owner = "Johnson";

const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
car = {type:"Volvo", model:"EX60", color:"red"};    // ERROR
```

[W3SCHOOLS - FONTE](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp)

Answer (score 1):

> Por causa do EcmaScript 6 vejo exemplos que declaram objetos literais
>   com a palavra reservada const. Isso é feito para manter o objeto
>   imutável ou é apenas uma proteção para evitar que a variável seja
>   sobrescrita?

**R: sua resposta esta abaixo de acordo com a MDN, segue o link:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Traduzido no Google!

Essa declaração cria uma constante cujo escopo pode ser global ou local para o bloco no qual ela é declarada. As constantes globais não se tornam propriedades do objeto `window`, diferentemente das variáveis ​​`var`. Um inicializador para uma constante é necessário; isto é, você deve especificar seu valor na mesma declaração em que é declarado (o que faz sentido, dado que não pode ser alterado mais tarde). **A declaração `const` cria uma referência somente leitura para um valor**. Isso não significa que o valor que ele contém é imutável, apenas que o identificador da variável não pode ser reatribuído. Por exemplo, no caso em que o conteúdo é um objeto, isso significa que o conteúdo do objeto (por exemplo, suas propriedades) pode ser alterado. Todas as considerações sobre a "zona morta temporal" aplicam-se a `let` e `const`. Uma constante não pode compartilhar seu nome com uma função ou variável no mesmo escopo.

Comment: Pelo que entendi essa prática visa proteger de variáveis e funções com o mesmo nome e também evitar a sobrescrita do valor de forma indevida.

Comment: @rcs Na teoria sim mas não confie sempre nisso, na verdade a proteção é o conjunto da logica do seu sistema... como foi dito acima "A declaração const cria uma referência somente leitura para um valor" mas não estamos 100% seguros se o seu objetivo é isso, um exemplo é os navegadores e versões... esse ano foi detectado falhas de segurança um alguns navegadores, tipo chrome v71, normal, estamos em constante evolução, segurança é um fator importante hoje na era da inteligencia artificial.

Comment: Meu comentário não foi em relação a segurança na web, mas sim em relação a proteger de eventuais falhas do próprio programador em sobrescrever valores por falta de atenção e redeclarar variáveis por esquecimento.

Comment: @rcs positivo, corretíssimo.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, no ES6, você pode declarar as variáveis usando `let` ou `const`. Como você mesmo disse, `const` é para criar constantes, ou seja, você declara uma vez e não vai mais reatribuir o valor. No caso do `let`, você pode reatribuir o valor (comum em loops, por exemplo).

A diferença principal do `let` e `const` para o `var` é o escopo. Veja a diferença entre os códigos abaixo:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // faça alguma coisa
}

console.log('O valor de i é ', i);

// irá imprimir "O valor de i é 9"
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // faça alguma coisa
}

console.log('O valor de i é ', i);

// irá ocorrer o erro "ReferenceError: i is not defined", pois a variável i só existe dentro do bloco do for
```

Resumindo, variáveis declaradas com `let` e `const` possuem escopo de bloco, enquanto variáveis declaradas com `var` somente possuem escopo de função, e não de bloco.