# Dúvidas sobre const do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variáveis

me ajuda a entender o const.
Para mim, uma const ao ser declarada, eu preciso atribuir um valor para essa variável. Uma vez que eu declaro esse valor (inicializo ela), eu não posso alterar, ou seja, atribuir um outro valor. Mas eu me deparei com essa situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Variável word possui uma string ‘Javascript’ e no final essa mesma variável possui um array vazio.
Eu sei que mesmo criando um objeto do tipo const, eu consigo mudar os valores das propriedades desse objeto, nesse caso o array também é objeto, teria alguma explicação nesse contexto similar? E aquela variável sorteado, nesse caso ela é do tipo number, porque é possível mudar o valor daquela const? Pesquisei sobre esse assunto, mas não achei algo que explicasse o porquê de ser possível mudar.

Código:

```
const word = 'JavaScript'.split(''); 
const letrasEmbaralhadas = [];

while (word.length){
    const sorteado = parseInt(Math.random() * word.length);
    const letraSelecionada = word.splice(sorteado, 1)[0];
    letrasEmbaralhadas.push(letraSelecionada);
}


console.log(word)
console.log(letrasEmbaralhadas)
```

Comment: No caso de objetos, o valor da constante é uma referência ao objeto, e essa referência é que não pode ser trocada. Em outras palavras, você não pode substituir o objeto para o qual a constante aponta. Cada objeto em si, porém, é independente e pode ter suas propriedades alteradas estando ou não guardado em uma constante.

Comment: "Variável word possui uma string ‘Javascript’ e no final essa mesma variável possui um array vazio.". Não, a const word armazenou o resultado final da aplicação de split na palavra, que é um array das letras, no caso `['J', 'a', 'v', 'a', 'S', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't']`.

Comment: Imaginei, mas por que a variável sorteado tem o seu valor alterado durante a execução do loop while?

Comment: @Benilson, mas no console.log na linha 11, deu um array vazio. Então ali na variável letraSelecionada que utiliza o método splice, eu removo um item do array word e esse retorno desse método, eu armazeno nessa variável letraSelecionada, certo? Para mim, por ser const a variável word, eu não poderia tirar letra ou alterar essa variável, mas pelo jeito eu estava enganado.

Comment: *A "variável" sorteado tem o seu valor alterado durante a execução do loop* por que a cada passagem do loop é criado um novo contexto onde é criada uma nova `const sorteado`. E palavra chave `const` define uma constante por valor para tipos primitivos e no caso de tipos por referência a constante é referencia para um objeto cujo o suas propriedades podem ser alteradas.

Comment: Agora entendi, @AugustoVasques. Fiz a pergunta, porque geralmente quando pessoal ensina sobre let, var e const, eles não chegam citar essas possibilidades de cenário, aí surgiu essa dúvida.

Comment: Acho que esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383179/por-que-objetos-literais-s%c3%a3o-declarados-com-const-no-javascript-atualmente) pode te ajudar.

Comment: Leia sobre [*hoisting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) e depois leia sobre [`var`, `let` e `const`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/3635). De resto leia os links acima (na caixa azul acima da pergunta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo suas perguntas...

> Variável `word` possui uma string *Javascript* e no final essa mesma
> variável possui um array vazio.

Não, ao fazer `const word = 'JavaScript'.split('');` em momento algum a [constante](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) `word` referenciou uma String, na verdade a constante `word` ao ser declarada fará a referência ao resultado da aplicação do método [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) que divide uma String em uma lista ordenada de substrings, coloca essas substrings em um array e o retorna, portanto constante `word` ao ser declarada irá referenciar um array.

> Eu sei que mesmo criando um objeto do tipo `const`, eu consigo mudar os
> valores das propriedades desse objeto, nesse caso o array também é
> objeto, teria alguma explicação nesse contexto similar?

Veja as preposições:

- *"...criando um objeto do tipo `const`, eu consigo mudar os
  valores das propriedades desse objeto....*
- *"...nesse caso o array também é objeto..."*

Acho aqui o problema se dá por conta da terminologia que está usando, está está causando confusão. Simplificando:

**Você não criou um objeto do tipo `const`**. Na verdade você declarou uma constante, cujo seu valor é a referência a um objeto e no caso de constante a referência ao objeto é fixa porém as propriedades do objeto referenciado inicialmente podem ser modificadas, propriedades podem ser acrescidas e propriedades podem ser removidas.

> E aquela variável `sorteado`, nesse caso ela é do tipo number, porque é
> possível mudar o valor daquela `const`?

A constante `sorteado` não tem o seu valor alterado. Ocorre que a declaração da constante `sorteado` é feita dentro uma [declaração de bloco](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) dentro de uma declaração [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while). Acontece que durante a execução do loop a cada iteração  é criado um novo contexto onde é feita uma nova declaração para constante em questão.

Constante e tipos primitivos:

Em *JavaScript*, tipo de dados primitivo é um dado que não é um objeto e não possui métodos ou propriedades.
Em *JavaScript* existem 7 tipos de dados primitivos:

- [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/String)
- [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Number)
- [bigint](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/BigInt)
- [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Boolean)
- [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/undefined)
- [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Symbol)
- [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Null)

Todos os tipos primitivos são imutáveis, ou seja se definir uma constante para um tipo primitivo essa é definida por valor.

**Deve ficar bem claro** é que em *Javascript* existem [wrappers nativos para os tipos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Primitive#wrappers_em_javascript) que são objetos criados ou através do operador [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) ou no envolvimento automaticamente de tipos primitivos ao ler resultados de métodos, funções, propriedades e variáveis. Exceto por `null` e `undefined`, todos os valores primitivos têm wrappers equivalentes:

- [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)
- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [Bigint](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)
- [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)
- [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Veja o exemplo

```js
//Declaração de um tipo primitivo string.
const txt1 = "Stack Overflow";
txt1.teste = "Essa propriedade não será definida e sua leitura retorna undefined.";
console.log(txt1.teste)

//Declaração do objeto String.
const txt2 = new String("Stack Overflow");
txt2.teste = "Já essa propriedade sim será definida.";
console.log(txt2.teste)
```

Use o método [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) para congelar um objeto. Um objeto congelado não pode mais ser alterado:

- impede que novas propriedades sejam adicionadas.
- impede que propriedades existentes sejam removidas.
- impede a alteração de [enumerabilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).
- impede a capacidade de reconfiguração da propriedades existentes.
- impede que os valores das propriedades existentes sejam alterados.
- impede que seu protótipo seja alterado. .

```js
const arr = ["C", "C++", "ObjC", "C#", "Java"];

Object.freeze(arr); //Congela o array

arr.push("Basic"); //Tenta modificar o array

console.log(arr);
```