# BigInt é um tipo primitivo?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, tipagem, bigint

Na documentação do site da **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Primitive)** afirma que existem apenas **`6`** tipos primitivos na linguagem: `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Null`, `undefined` e `Symbol (es6)`.

No mesmo site, [este link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) descreve o tipo **`BigInt`** assim:

> BigInt é um objeto **nativo** que fornece um modo de representar números inteiros maiores que 253, que é o maior número que o JavaScript consegue, com exatidão, representar com o tipo primitivo Number.

Seguido da sintaxe do tipo:

```
BigInt(value);
```

- O que seria um objeto nativo?
- Este tipo é ou não é primitivo?

Comment: Posso muda o título? Seria *"O que são Objetos Nativos e Tipos Primitivos?"*.

Comment: Pode ficar à vontade @AugustoVasques :)

Comment: Agora com as respostas já dadas ficou mais complicado mudar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [versão em inglês do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) diz que há 7 tipos primitivos, sendo um deles o `bigint` (provavelmente a versão em português está desatualizada).

Já a [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types) chama estes tipos de "*Language Types*", e na [seção de "*Numeric Types*"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types) é dito que `Number` e `BigInt` são os dois tipos numéricos *built-in* ("embutidos", mas é comum dizer que são tipos "nativos", ou seja, que "já vem com a linguagem" - [embora a definição de nativo seja um pouco mais complicada que isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458760/112052)).

Já em [outro trecho da especificação](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-primitive-value) há a definição de *primitive value*:

> *member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, **BigInt**, Symbol, or String as defined in clause 6*
> (e o item 6 é o link que já vimos acima, que define os *Language Types*).

Já sobre o objeto `BigInt`, veja também a [documentação em inglês](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), que diz o seguinte:

> *BigInt is a primitive wrapper object used to represent and manipulate primitive bigint values*

Ou seja, é um *wrapper* para o *language type* `bigint` (ver também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/553735/112052), mas basicamente, o tipo "primitivo" não possui métodos, enquanto o objeto sim, além de outras diferenças citadas na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)).

Na especificação da linguagem há [este outro trecho](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-bigint-value) que diferencia ambos:

> **4.4.28 BigInt value**
> primitive value corresponding to an arbitrary-precision integer value
> ...
> **4.4.30 BigInt object**
> member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in BigInt constructor

Ou seja, existe o "primitivo" `bigint` e seu respectivo objeto *wrapper* `BigInt` (embora a especificação da linguagem não use o termo "*wrapper*" para estes casos, portanto parece ser uma terminologia da MDN). E ambos são "nativos" (no sentido de que "fazem parte da linguagem").

Answer (score 4):

Quase tudo que achar em português que qualquer pessoa pode pôr a mão terá erros. Isso parece ser cultural, as pessoas não se preocupam com a qualidade do texto nem mesmo quando vão fazer uma simples tradução. Então o melhor que pode aprender aqui é consultar documentação em inglês, especialmente as que são do tipo *wiki*.

Na [documentação original em inglês](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) vemos que sequer tem o termo nativo. Ser nativo é uma coisa, ser [primitivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101) é outra.

Tem outros erros na tradução, ela ensina errado. Toda MDN e outros sites são assim. Tem erros em várias páginas da MDN em inglês também, que também é *wiki*, mas é melhor.

Mesmo a expressão usada foi mal interpretada:

> primitive wrapper object

em português ficaria:

> objeto que encapsula/embrulha um primitivo

Portanto `BigInt` é um objeto de biblioteca e dentro dele tem um dos tais tipos primitivos da linguagem, algo que a linguagem entende de forma especial.

> O que seria um objeto nativo?

Talvez possamos dizer que o nativo é um tipo que o processador entende de forma direta sem precisar compor ou tratar de forma especial e o primitivo  é um tipo que a linguagem trata de forma especial e o compilador entende alguns aspectos dele que se fosse um tipo de biblioteca não poderia ser tão poderoso.

Mas essa definição pode não ser a usada pelo JavaScript. Em geral não gosto dos dois termos, mas o nativo neste contexto não costuma ser bom ou mesmo faz muito sentido em uma linguagem de tão alto nível, inclusive a linguagem não te deixa acessar exatamente como no processador. Me parece ter sido usado equivocadamente no texto.

> Este tipo é ou não é primitivo?

No *link* ali em cima eu falo que o próprio termo primitivo é usado de forma diferente em contextos diferentes, e o resumo acabei de escrever.

Comment: "Quase tudo que achar em português que qualquer pessoa pode pôr a mão terá erros", rapaz forte isso daí hein?! O recomendado seria sempre ler as docs em inglês então?

Comment: Sim, a chance é bem maior de acertar.

Comment: @utente Não é questão de "forte", é um fato (triste, mas ainda sim, verdade): na nossa área a esmagadora maioria do material de qualidade está em inglês. Pouca coisa é traduzida, e desse pouco, uma pequena parte é **bem** traduzida. Claro que também tem muita porcaria em inglês, mas as docs oficiais em geral costumam ser melhores do que as traduções

Comment: @utente tem casos gravíssimos, algum "especialista" (pensei outra coisa, mas viola o código de conduta) conseguiu na documentação OFICIAL do PHP enfiar um `md5(uniqid(` como exemplo de uso, que mina completamente a finalidade do treco. Veja só a original https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php e a BR: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php -

Comment: Nossa pessoal, triste e desanimador hein. Gera aquela dúvida na galera então né o que estudar primeiro, uma linguagem de programação ou a língua inglesa, muitos não conseguem conciliar os 2, ou é um ou é outro :(

Comment: @utente, porque você acha que somos tão "chatos" aqui no site? A verdade é que nós não somos chatos, nós apenas trazemos nossas publicações a um nível que no mínimo possa trazer informações tão boas quanto as estrangeiras, a pena é que esse mínimo é combatido por alguns usuários que no julgam exigentes.