# Diferença entre declarar com var ou let em javascript?

Tags: javascript, declaração-de-variável

Oi, meu primeiro post aqui. Estou começando a estudar javascript e me surgiu uma dúvida entre quando declarar uma variável com var ou let.

**Eu vou usar um código com condicional como exemplo:**

```
let idade = 19;
let acesso = '';

if (idade < 16) {
  acesso = 'proibido';
} else if (idade >= 16 && idade <= 18) {
  acesso = 'permitido somente quando acompanhado por um maior de idade';
} else {
  acesso = 'permitido';
console.log(acesso)
}


if (idade < 10) {
  acesso = 'proibido';
} else if (idade >= 11 && idade <= 15) {
  acesso = 'permitido';
} else {
  acesso = 'proibido maiores de 18';
console.log(acesso)
}
```

O que eu entendi sobre var e let é que quando quero que uma variável seja global usamos o var, e quando queremos utilizar a variável somente em um bloco utilizamos let.

Acho que não está muito claro para mim o que é um bloco e por isso me surgiu a dúvida.
Eu pensava que um bloco seria entre os colchetes {}, no caso desse código, pensei que as variáveis declaradas com let no início só serviriam para o primeiro caso e no segundo caso daria erro, por não ter variáveis declaradas, já que estão em colchetes separados.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206117/var-const-ou-let-qual-usar

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [var, const ou let? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206117/var-const-ou-let-qual-usar)

Comment: O problema do seu caso é que você declarou o `let` no escopo geral, não dentro de um bloco ( entre `{` e `}`, como você disse)

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelTavares, super entendi! Não sei como votar na tua resposta mas obrigado!

Comment: Tem uma setinha para cima do lado, mas isso não foi uma resposta, isso é um comentário rs. Sem problemas :)