# Como fazer o botão "calcular" executar a soma de x e y?

Tags: javascript, html

Tudo funciona, menos o botão. O resultado não aparece. Segue o código abaixo:

```js
function calcular(){
    "valorx" = document.getElementById('valorx').value 
    "valory" = document.getElementById('valory').value 

    "resultado" = parseFloat("valorx") + parseFloat("valory")

    document.getElementById('resultado').value = resultadoalert('Cálculo realizado com sucesso!')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body bgcolor="#fedcd2"></body>
<h1>Calculadora</h1>

<br>
<label>Valor X</label>
<input type="number" id="valorx">
<br>
<br>
<label>Valor Y</label>
<input type="number" id="valory">

<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

<br>
<label>Resultado</label>
<br>
<input type ="number" id="resultado">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"valorx" = document.getElementById('valorx').value` - essas aspas não fazem sentido, deveria ser apenas `valorx = document.getElementById('valorx').value` (o mesmo vale para as outras variáveis)

Comment: Troque `"valorx" =` por `let valorx =` e o mesmo para `let valory =`

Comment: @CypherPotato fiz isso, mas continua sem funcionar. Também tirei as aspas desnecessárias, mas sem resultado, também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem um monte de problemas, mas vamos começar um por um.

Na declaração de uma variável em Javascript, você sempre usa a sintaxe:

```js
var alice = valor;
let bob = valor;
const samuel = valor;
```

[Nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206117/var-const-ou-let-qual-usar?noredirect=1&lq=1) tem a explicação da diferença entre `var`, `let` e `const`.

No entanto, você abusou de strings literais em seu código, o que é `"uma string"` é somente o valor de uma expressão, e não deve ser utilizada no nome de variáveis.

```
var valor_x = document.getElementById('valorx').value
```

No caso acima, `var` é a palavra-chave de criar uma variável, `valor_x` é o nome da variável, `=` o operador de atribuição, e `document.getElementById('valorx').value` é a expressão.

Nesse caso, você inicia com a declaração de uma variável, seu nome e seu operador de atribuição, logo com uma expressão. Expressões podem ser `"strings"`, `414` (inteiros) ou outras expressões não-literais como a do exemplo acima.

Eu não vou nem questionar o abuso de `<br>` no seu código, provavelmente ainda está aprendendo como utilizar o HTML e CSS. Em breve estará utilizando `flexbox` e outros elementos para ajustar o layout do seu código.

É muito difícil o `<br/>` ser utilizado.

Além disso, no seu código original, logo após `value = resultado` já começava imediatamente a outra linha, e como você não separou as declarações com `;`, o interpretador irá ler tudo na mesma linha, e logo irá jogar uma exceção de sintaxe errada.

O separador de declarações `;` é opcional no Javascript, mas é útil para ter vários procedimentos em uma única linha:

```
var x = "olá mundo"; alert(x);
```

O código acima sem os `;` iria causar um erro.

Aqui está uma versão corrigida do seu código, com as explicações que mencionei acima:

```js
function calcular(){
    let valorx = document.getElementById('valorx').value 
    let valory = document.getElementById('valory').value 

    let resultado = parseFloat(valorx) + parseFloat(valory)

    document.getElementById('resultado').value = resultado
    alert('Cálculo realizado com sucesso!')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body bgcolor="#fedcd2"></body>
<h1>Calculadora</h1>

<br>
<label>Valor X</label>
<input type="number" id="valorx">
<br>
<br>
<label>Valor Y</label>
<input type="number" id="valory">

<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

<br>
<label>Resultado</label>
<br>
<input type ="number" id="resultado">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puxa, obrigada pela ajuda! Pelo menos agora a mensagem de alerta finalmente aparece na tela. Meu professor passou esse exercício, mas não explicou essas coisas. Muito obrigada! Me ajudou bastante <3

Comment: Por favor, considere marcar a resposta como "correta" logo após o ícone de voto ao lado da minha pergunta. Fico feliz por ter ajudado.