# Requisição AJAX com FOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, for

Bom pessoal como eu posso imprimir corretamente o Hello World, utilizando requisição AJAX, dentro de um for?

Minha dúvida real é: entender porque o for executa todo o seu loop na primeira requisição ajax, para somente depois executar loop na segunda requisição ajax?

**Hoje tenho esse resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código HTML e JS**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <script src="../jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

});

function call(){
    for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'json.json',
            type: 'get',   
            success: function(data){
            call_1(data['data'].one);
            $.ajax({
                url:'json.json',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data){
                    call_2(data['data'].two);
                }
            });
            }
        });
    }
}

function call_1(res){
    $('body').append(res);
}

function call_2(res){
    $('body').append(res+'<hr>');
}

</script>
```

**Meu arquivo json.json:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "one": "Hello",
        "two": " World"
    }
}
```

Resolvi enviando junto com as opções do ajax o:

```
async: false,
```

Ficando assim:

```
function call(){
    for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'json.json',
            type: 'get',   
            success: function(data){
            call_1(data['data'].one);
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url:'json.json',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data){
                    call_2(data['data'].two);
                }
            });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Que parte do código podes mudar e que parte não podes mudar?

Comment: A parte do ajax.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor? Eu perguntei qual **podes** mudar e qual **não** podes...

Comment: Então, 
na verdade eu queria entender porque o for executa todo o seu loop na primeira requisição ajax, para somente depois executar loop na segunda requisição ajax.

Comment: Lê esta resposta e diz se responde à tua dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/como-usar-o-valor-atual-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-numa-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mais-interna/1238#1238

Comment: Sergio, não resolveu usando o let.
=(

Comment: O problema ou solução não é o `let`... é não compreenderes ainda a natureza assíncrona do ajax. Se leres essa pergunta e a minha resposta lá vais perceber esse mecanismo e vai ajudar-te a perceber o problema aqui. Mas tens de ler tudo, de querer perceber... lê e diz-me de que maneira estão relacionadas as duas perguntas?

Comment: Entendi!
Dei uma lida sobre as funções assíncronas e ajustei o código, funcionando corretamente agora. Coloquei junto com os settings do ajax a linha:
async: true,

Assim ele faz uma requisição e após a outra.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma função recursiva ao invés de um for

```js
function call(index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.json',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            call_1(data['data'].one);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'json.json',
                type: 'get',
                success: function (data) {
                    call_2(data['data'].two);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (index < 5) {
            index++;
            call(index);
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

Lembrando onde chamar a função call começar com o index 0

Comment: Continua executando da mesma forma. Link: http://prntscr.com/lr705t
Vlww Mateus.

Comment: Acho que agora vai , ali onde tem o 50 é o tempo que vai espera até chamar a função novamente